# Grouping and calculating mean of non zero values

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the group by and summarize function to  calculate means of non zero values.

Example:=

```
Group  Val
A       3
A       0
A       3
B       1 
B       0 
B       1
```

```
test %>% 
    group_by(Group) %>%
    summarise(Mean = mean(test$Val[ Val  != 0 ])
```

The desired output should be

```
Group    Mean 
A         3
B         1
```

Instead I get

```
Group    Mean 
A         2
B         0.66
```

Comment: When using `dplyr`, it is best to avoid `$`, very rarely needed. Also why not first filter?

Comment: `test %>% group_by(Group) %>% filter(Val != 0) %>% summarise(Mean = mean(Val))`

Comment: Thank you very much! 

In my summarise function I am looking at dealing with negative values and positive values separately too. Is there a conditional statement I can inculcate in the mean function itself or would I need to filter multiple tables for this?

Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To answer both of your questions we need to create a new sample data:

```
set.seed(123)
test <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("A", "B"), 5), 
                   Val = replicate(10, sample(c(-3:3), 1, replace = TRUE)))
```

As @Jon Spring suggested you can get the mean for each group without zeros by filtering them:

```
require(tidyverse)

test %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  filter(Val != 0) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Val))
```

To get the mean without zeros for each group and for the sign - we can create a new variable for sign and now `group_by` group and sign:

```
test %>% 
  mutate(sign = ifelse(Val > 0, "positive", "negative")) %>% 
  group_by(Group, sign) %>%
  filter(Val != 0) %>%
  summarise(Mean = mean(Val))
```

Result:

```
  Group sign      Mean
  <fct> <chr>    <dbl>
1 A     negative -1   
2 A     positive  3   
3 B     negative -3   
4 B     positive  2.67
```